# What is the default path of the source of Haskell modules (Prelude, etc.)?

Tags: haskell

I want to browse the source of the installed Haskell modules on my machine.
What is the default search path of Haskell's `import`?

Comment: This is not in general possible.  There is no requirement that Haskell modules be installed as source.  GHC does not install Haskell modules as source.

Comment: If all you're looking for is the source to browse as a human reader (not as a piece of software), you can find it on [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/src/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So there's a bit of an impedance mismatch here, since packages are generally installed as binaries (though the most popular way to get the binaries is to build from source). Still, it's not too bad. The rough plan will be to map from module name to package/version pair, then ask cabal to unpack a copy of that version of the package.

Let's say I wanted to read the source for `Data.Text`. Then:

```
% ghc-pkg find-module Data.Text
/usr/local/lib/ghc-8.2.1/package.conf.d
    (no packages)
/home/dmwit/.ghc/x86_64-linux-8.2.1/package.conf.d
    text-1.2.2.2
% cabal unpack text-1.2.2.2
Unpacking to text-1.2.2.2/
```

You will now have a `text-1.2.2.2` directory containing the source for the `text` package -- including a file in `text-1.2.2.2/Data/Text.hs` that contains the source for the `Data.Text` module.

Comment: Thank You, this is helpful.